# What is the maximum value of a LayerMask in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity

What is the maximum value of a LayerMask in Unity (the value when all layers are included)? And how can I find it using C# bitwise operations?

I tried `~0` but it shows `-1` in intellisense.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit:** I actually realised there is a [Physics.AllLayers](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.AllLayers.html) field that is returning the same value.

---

I ran the following code, and it conviced me enough to believe that `~0` is the maximum value of layermask. All results were `true`.

```
int t1 = 1 << 1;
int t2 = 1 << 2;
int t3 = 1 << 3;
int t4 = 1 << 4;
int t5 = 1 << 5;

int max = ~0;

bool r1 = (max & t1) == t1;
bool r2 = (max & t2) == t2;
bool r3 = ((max | t3) & t1) == t1;
bool r4 = ((max | t4) & t2) == t2;
bool r5 = ((max | t5) & t5) == t5;

Debug.Log(r1);
Debug.Log(r2);
Debug.Log(r3);
Debug.Log(r4);
Debug.Log(r5);
```